# Independent random shuffling within a loop

Tags: python, loops, random, shuffle

I am using the module `random` to shuffle an array of `n` elements. I need to do it `m` times, and I am not completely sure that the shuffling happening every time is independent.

See an example bellow:

```
for i in range(10):
    a = list(range(1,20))
    random.shuffle(a)
    print("\n\nSequence of numbers ")
    for item in a:
        print(item)
```

Can I be completely sure that the second time I `shuffle` list `a` will be completely independent from the first time?

Looking at the results I have the impression that the output is not independent. But maybe it is only my impression.

For example, an output that I get for 4 numbers and 4 repetions is the following [1, 3, 2, 4], [1, 3, 2,4], [4, 1, 3, 2] and [1, 4, 3, 2]. Does this happen by chance? Probably yes. But I want to be sure.

Context: it could be that I want to order the n question of an exam I am giving to m students. But I want that this process is done independently for every single student.

Comment: What *is* the output? Why do you get this impression from it?

Comment: Humans are [notoriously bad](https://cocosci.berkeley.edu/tom/papers/hard.pdf) at evaluating randomness. How certain do you need to be that the shuffles are "independent"? What do you *mean* by independent - note that the exact same order could  occur again, randomly. Have you considered [`urandom`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.urandom), if it is so crucial?

Comment: Yes, I know that humans are not good in evaluating randomness. But I am just wondering if I need to take some extra care in my code (such as reseting the seed) or if it is fine like this. I am not familiar with this python module.

Comment: For example, an output that I get is the following

Comment: **Edit the question**. Please add some context, too; what is this *for*?

Comment: For example, an output that I get for 4 numbers and 4 repetions is the following [1, 3, 2, 4], [1, 3, 2,4], [4, 1, 3, 2] and [1, 4, 3, 2]. Does this happen by chance? Probably yes. But I want to be sure.

Comment: *Could* it happen by chance? Of course, you get get `[1, 2, 3, 4]` every time, that doesn't mean it isn't random. *Is it* happening by chance? No, `random` is strictly *psuedorandom*, not truly random. Does that matter? Almost certainly not! Why does it matter if two students get the questions in the same order (or an order that is somehow related by [a process they know little about](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister))?

Comment: So jonrsharpe. What you mean is that what I am doing is just fine, given that I am aware that this is pseudorandom, right? It might be a stupid question, but I am serached a lot of questions before I posted mine, and it could not find the exact answer I was seraching for.

Comment: Note that there are 24 permutations of 4 numbers. `1/24` isn't *that* small. About 4% of the times you should get the same permutation, 4% is small but not really small. Also, most permutations do have some number in a common place so it's normal that they look similar... try it with 100 elements and they should look more random.

Comment: It's hard to tell you whether it is *fine* or not; why do you want or need them to be independent?

Answer (score 1):

You can test this. Note that there are exactly 4!=24 *permutations* of the numbers `1,2,3,4`. You should expect that in a random sampling each of these permutations come up equally likely. To prove to yourself that this results in the *uniform distribution* that you are looking for, sample the sequences:

```
import random, math
from collections import Counter

samples = 1000000

a = list(range(1,5))
C = Counter()

for _ in xrange(samples):
    random.shuffle(a)
    C[tuple(a)] += 1

import pylab as plt
permutations = math.factorial(4)
expected = float(samples)/permutations
plt.plot(C.values())
plt.plot([0,permutations],[expected,expected],'r--')
plt.ylim(0,expected*2.01)   
plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that the red dash is the theoretical expected values and the blue line is the values we get from sampling. From this I am pretty confident that we are getting a uniform distribution, but we could always use a [Kolmogorov Smirnov test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) to quantify it. What this *doesn't* test for is correlation between the sequences. This again could be tested for using pairs of sequences generated with some time lag, but the Fisher-Yates shuffle used by pythons `random.shuffle` does a good job at preventing that.

Answer (score 0):

For practical purposes, successive calls to random.shuffle are independent. It takes log(N!)/log(2) bits of state to describe a unique ordering of elements, and a quick check of random.getstate() shows that the default pseudorandom number generator actually uses 20000 bits of state. To reach a meaningful overlap we'd need to consume all those bits of entropy.

So we need M*log(N!)/log(2)>=20000 to have a known (but ridiculously hard to predict) correlation. That's not impossible to imagine; it's about 28 questions for 200 students. The odds of that correlation outweighing the fact that they have 304888344611713860501504000000 possible orderings, however, is slim.

Answer (score 0):

This is the actual code from Python's `random` module:

```
for i in reversed(xrange(1, len(x))):
    # pick an element in x[:i+1] with which to exchange x[i]
    j = _int(random() * (i+1))
    x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
```

looks like a proper Fisher-Yates to me, and totally independent of
any previous runs.